# .net dll instantiation on 32 and 64 bit machines

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, 64-bit, 32-bit

I am fuzzy on when you can reference a 32 bit dll in visual studio (c# or vb) on a 64 bit machine.

I am trying to do one now (Interop.PDF2IMGOCXLib.dll or just PDF2IMGOCXLib.dll) and it errors out with the message:

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {66BBFF81-C832-411C-B81E-883C3A96CFD8} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

This same code works on a 32 bit machine however.

It is a 3rd party dll, so I cannot edit it.

Please correct me where I am wrong.  I thought that Visual Studio was a 32 bit application that would allow reference to 32 and 64 bit references.

I have tried several things:

1. Ensure the compile>Platform setting is (x86) for 32 bit.
2. Registered the dll (in many places), including wow64 folder.  Registering it with regsvr32 errors out with standard "The module dllname was loaded but the entry point dllregisterserver was not found". Registering it with Regasm.  It says it worked fine.

The reference error that occurs in Visual Studio occurs right on the declare statement

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()
    Dim x As New PDF2IMGOCXLib.Pdf2Img

    Return
End Sub
```

End Module

So, in general, when can 32 bit dlls be used in visual studio on a 64 bit machine?

Maybe something about the dll only working if it was just targeted for 32 bit systems, but not if targeted for for both 32 and 64 bit systems.

Any thoughts?

Comment: When you move from one machine to another, the stuff that does not normally move along as well are components that were installed on the old machine.  Which is the root cause of this exception message.  You can get a second opinion from SysInternals' Process Monitor.  You'll see your app searching the registry and not finding the key.  Compare against the trace on the old machine, verify what the trace tells you with Regedit.exe

Answer (score 0):

1. %systemroot%\SysWoW64\regsvr32.exe is for win32
2. systemroot%\System32\regsvr32.exe is for x64
3. you should use %systemroot%\SysWoW64\regsvr32.exe instead of %systemroot%\System32\regsvr32.exe to regist your COM control
4. make sure your exe is win32 only
5. by the way, if the windows versions of the two pc are different, try to use "Compatibility Mode" to start your exe.